# replace value in a dataframe with values from another dataframe based on column names and values

Tags: pandas, numpy

So I have one dataframe with multiple variables, both categorical and numerical.

```
Var0 Var1 Var2
 1    a    1
 1    a    5                 
 0    c    8            
 1    d    15
```

The second dataframe contains all column names from the first one in a column, the value that I want to bring BBB and a cutoff which can be both an interval such as (1.0,2.0] or a category such as:

```
Variable   Cutoff     BBB
Var1          a       0.2
Var1          b       0.3
Var1          c       0.8
Var1          d       0.1 
Var2       (1, 5]     0.8                 
Var2       (6, 10]    0.1   
Var2       (11, 20]   0.3 
Var0          1       0.3
Var0          0       0.5
```

I want to replace the values from the first dataframe with the corresponding values from the second dataframe (the ones that satisfy those conditions).

The expected output should look like this:

```
Var0  Var1 Var2
0.3   0.2   0.8
0.3   0.2   0.8                 
0.5   0.8   0.1            
0.3   0.1   0.3
```

Regards,

Vlad

Comment: please provide the expected output (as **text**)

Comment: please edit the question and append it with the same format as I used to edit your question

Comment: Do you `melt` the second dataframe? It would (probably) be easy if not.

Comment: The second dataframe is the result of some computations made using the values from the first one.

Comment: then, it might be easier to just explain what you want to achieve in the end, the intermediate df2 can probably be skipped

Comment: I'm computing weights of evidence based on group category for each variable in df1. Basically I bin all variables and do woe on each bin. Also, df2 is useful in its own way as I many times I need it in that specific way to show this woe for each group of a variable.